# get values from XML file in my Titanium Project

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I am having the following .xml which i used in my android project.now,am trying to create the same in iPhone using titanium.Can some one tell me how to get this values from the xml file and show them in a table view.? if i give MainCategories the 3 values in it should appear in the table view.Also can some one tell me is there any other better option to achieve this?or can we use plist??thank you.

```
<string-array name="MainCategories">
    <item>Acceleration</item>
    <item>Angle</item>
    <item>Area</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="Acceleration_array">
    <item>meter/sq sec</item>
    <item>km/sq sec</item>
    <item>mile/sq sec</item>
    <item>yard/sq sec</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="Angle_array">
    <item>degree</item>
    <item>radian</item>
    <item>grad</item>
    <item>gon</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This.

var result = [];
    var fileName = 'arrays1.xml'; //save xml file 
      var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({ data : result, width : '100%', height : '100%'   });

```
function readXML(fileName)
{

var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName); 
var xmltext = file.read().text; 
var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext); 

var parentNodeLength = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('string-array').length; 
for (var i = 0; i < parentNodeLength; i++) { 
var attrValue = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('string-array').item(i).attributes.getNamedItem('name').nodeValue;
if (attrValue === 'Angle_array') {

    var parentNode = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('string-array').item(i);
    var subNodeLength = parentNode.getElementsByTagName('item').length;

    for (var j = 0; j < subNodeLength; j++) {

        var title = parentNode.getElementsByTagName('item').item(j).text;
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height : 110
        });
        var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            text : title
        });

        row.add(label);
        result.push(row);
    }
}

}
}
readXML(fileName); 
tableView.setData(result);
win1.add(tableView); 
win1.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not familiar with titanium but maybe this should help you out:

```
var result = this.responseText;
var xml = Ti.XML.parseString(result);

var params = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("member");
var name = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
var value = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("string");
var data = [];

for (var i=0;i<params.item.length;i++) {
    Ti.API.log('Param '+i+': Name: '+n.item(i).text);
    Ti.API.log('Param '+i+': Value: '+v.item(i).text);

    // Add to array
    data.push({"name":n.item(i).text,"value":v.item(i).text});
}
```

copied from this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/4031/parsing-xml-struct)

for displaying it in uitableview, save your values in nsarray and display your array in tableview. here is a [tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/) for `UITableView`.